# How to perform inner join on a table with one to many relation?

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

This search uses various webpages in a database by matching values of metadata. Here value field has more than one value and I am not sure how to get only GRADUATE Science courses or something similar.
I have tried so many things but nothing works.

```
select distinct page.path,page.site_id,
  (select metadata_custom.value AS display_name
   from metadata_custom
   where field='academic search title'
     and page.id=metadata_custom.page_id) AS value,
   page.id
   from publish.page
   inner join metadata
     on page.metadata_id=metadata.id
   inner join metadata_custom
     on page.id=metadata_custom.page_id
   where field='acadsearch'
     and value like ('science%' AND 'graduate%");
```

Also, I have another query where I use
value like  '{$term}%'

some sample tables
TABLE PAGE:

```
id | account_id | site_id |  cms_id  | folder_id |  metadata_id | name |path | content
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 583 | 1 |   1 | e026b376c0a80123019b60bb23817853 | db2b800fc0a80123019b60bbb5e082cd| 2915 | rob-castillo| academics/undergraduate/social-work/rob-castillo | <region-render><div class="center_text">
<content/>
</div></region-render>   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 578 |  1 |   1 | e026b25fc0a80123019b60bb58c9f847 | db2b800fc0a80123019b60bbb5e082cd | 2887 | jeffrey-bulanda | academics/undergraduate/social-work/jeffrey-bulanda | <region-render><div class="center_text">
<content/>
</div></region-render> 

Table Metadata Custom

id | account_id | site_id | file_id  | folder_id | page | field |value 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 21713 |          1 |       1 |    NULL |      NULL |     563 | acadsearch | graduate                                                         |
| 21714 |          1 |       1 |    NULL |      NULL |     563 | acadsearch| rad2                                                                  |
| 21715 |          1 |       1 |    NULL |      NULL |     563 | override                 |                                                                       |
| 21716 |          1 |       1 |    NULL |      NULL |     563 | acadsearch | humanities                                                            |
| 21717 |          1 |       1 |    NULL |      NULL |     563 | acadsearch                 |                                                                       |
| 21718 |          1 |       1 |    NULL |      NULL |     563 | acadsearch | rad1                                                                 |
| 21719 |          1 |       1 |    NULL |      NULL |     563 | acadsearch | gwcugcampus                                                           |
| 21720 |          1 |       1 |    NULL |      NULL |     563 | breadcrumb               |                                                                       |
| 21721 |          1 |       1 |    NULL |      NULL |     563 | acadsearch                 |                                                                       |
| 21722 |          1 |       1 |    NULL |      NULL |     563 | acadsearch   | Psychology (BA)                                                       |
| 21723 |          1 |       1 |    NULL |      NULL |     563 | acadsearch | Psychology                                                            |
| 21724 |          1 |       1 |    NULL |      NULL |     563 | acadsearch | rad1                                                                  |
| 21725 |          1 |       1 |    NULL |      NULL |     563 | acadsearch | sciences                                                              |
| 21726 |          1 |       1 |    NULL |      NULL |     563 | acadsearch | gwcugcampus
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the whole query is supposed to do, but the last part of the query is incorrect anyhow:

```
value like ('science%' AND 'graduate%')
```

should probably be:

```
(value LIKE 'science%' OR value LIKE 'graduate%')
```

EDIT:

Based on the updated question and the comments below, I see no need for wildcard matching or weird joins. Please try the following query:

```
SELECT 
   p.`id`, p.`site_id`, p.`path`
FROM 
   `page` AS p,
   `metadata_custom` AS mc
WHERE
    p.`id` = mc.`page_id`
    AND mc.`field` =  'acadsearch'
    AND (
        mc.`value` =  'graduate'
        OR mc.`value` =  'rad1'
    )
GROUP BY
    p.`id`
```

To extend the search on more metadata values add more OR expressions.

The query in the question contains a subquery, which cannot be added without having single result rows for every page. That subquery should be executed as a separate query, which can be matched on page ID for every page returned with the above query:

```
SELECT
    `page_id`,
    `value` AS display_name
FROM
    `metadata_custom`
WHERE 
    `field` = 'academic search title'
    AND `page_id` IN (<insert page IDs comma separated>)
```

Comment: i have undergrad and grad science courses, and I want to display only if course is science and graduate, should match for both. Thanks

Comment: Checking a single value on two totally different values will never work. As you want a single row (and thus a single value for metadata_custom.value) per page.path, it's just not feasible. It could be possible by using two inner joins, each checking another value for metadata_custom.value. Providing such a query is not easy, as the table structures are unknown.

Comment: so I added this in the end? AND value LIKE '%science%'  inner join publish.metadata on publish.page.metadata_id=publish.metadata.id inner join publish.metadata_custom on publish.page.id=publish.metadata_custom.page_id where field='academic search keywords' 
AND value LIKE '%graduate%'

Comment: INNER JOINs are always executed on a given table (page in this case), so they should be placed in the FROM clause.

Comment: But i already have a inner join on page so I was wondering how can I insert another inner join. I am lost now!

Comment: You can alias tables, just like you would alias a field. Something like "INNER JOIN table AS t1 ON ...". But my suggestion is: don't try to do it all in a single query. Execute a simple query first, getting the right data from metadata_custom and use the outcome of that in another query. And then another query, as the need may be. There's little benefit from trying to push it all in a single query.

Comment: Yes, i agree, the querry that I have problme with is from one db, I am doing a union on same query on second db, already. Now I have to do an inner join!

Comment: Would it be possible to show this inner join on the same query, I am not sure how I would do it with a different where condition?

Comment: Yes, if you could supply the table structure and example data. Guessing those based on the given query could be erroneous. If you update the question with that information I'll give a new answer.

Comment: Okay, we have some problem where I can only query my database, ITS is pretty slow at giving me access to database structure. If it helps, this page has the download source of database http://www.hannonhill.com/kb/Database-Publishing/

thanks for your time and help.

Comment: I'll need example data as well. Without it the answer will still be guesswork.

Comment: I am sorry I don't have access to database right now, like I said that can take time. It's just the value part is comma separated and hence the problem with querying.

Comment: Hi Plenka, I just got access to db and I added two sample tables for you. Badly in need of pointers. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Plenka, I was able to do this on my own and it was pretty similar to your answer. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

if i'm understanding you correctly you want to get the data where the value field has science and graduate in it? this being the case if they have to be science then something then graduate then its

```
SELECT DISTINCT page.path,
                page.site_id,
                (SELECT metadata_custom.value AS display_name
                 FROM   metadata_custom
                 WHERE  field = 'academic search title'
                    AND page.id = metadata_custom.page_id) AS value,
                page.id
FROM   publish.page
       INNER JOIN metadata
               ON page.metadata_id = metadata.id
       INNER JOIN metadata_custom
               ON page.id = metadata_custom.page_id
WHERE  field = 'acadsearch'
   AND value LIKE 'science%graduate%'
```

or if it doesnt matter which way round they are then this

```
SELECT DISTINCT page.path,
                page.site_id,
                (SELECT metadata_custom.value AS display_name
                 FROM   metadata_custom
                 WHERE  field = 'academic search title'
                    AND page.id = metadata_custom.page_id) AS value,
                page.id
FROM   publish.page
       INNER JOIN metadata
               ON page.metadata_id = metadata.id
       INNER JOIN metadata_custom
               ON page.id = metadata_custom.page_id
WHERE  field = 'acadsearch'
   AND (value LIKE '%science%'
       AND value LIKE '%graduate%')
```

here the docs on mysql like
[Mysql like docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

Comment: so far I tried your second query and I am not getting results, .. value field has multiple values, about 50, depending on what has been checked. And I am trying to find graduate AND science match.Thanks a lot

Comment: do you get results when you omit the AND (value LIKE '%science%'
       AND value LIKE '%graduate%')

Comment: NO, I get results when I use the answer below, for OR condition. I just want both science and graduate to be true, AND is not working. Is there any other operator that can be used?

Comment: how are the different words in the value field seperated? commas, spaces?

Comment: then try  

    AND (value LIKE '%science%graduate%' OR value LIKE '%graduate%science%')

Comment: Would it matter if there are total  more than 50 comma separated values and science and graduate are not next to each other? Because the above didn't work. thanks a lot for your time and help.

Comment: are you sure there are results with both in the value field

Comment: oh yes! we have multiple values checked for each page. I am already displaying course for like undergrad and grad(single value matching), but now these double combinations is what I want.

Comment: you could do it the long way
AND value LIKE '%science%' AND metadata_custom.id IN (SELECT metadata_custom.id
                 FROM   metadata_custom
                 WHERE  field = 'academic search title'
                    AND metadata_custom.value LIKE '%graduate%'
                    AND page.id = metadata_custom.page_id)